# Deserializing flattened JSON to Java Object using Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

So I am currently using Jackson to deserialize JSON into complex java objects. Everything works well but I also have some fields such as:

```
{
  "foo.bar.baz":"qux"
}
```

which correspond to java objects such as:

```
class Foo {
    AnotherClass bar;
}

class AnotherClass {
    String baz;
}
```

Jackson is unable to figure out that the dots correspond to inner objects. Is there a way to get Jackson to be able to deserialize even on flattened fields such as the field in my example?

Comment: "foo.bar.baz" is not is not a valid JSON format

Comment: @CMPS: :) I like that your answer also is not in the correct format.

Comment: Don't know about implementations, but your example has your desired semantics if you use a YAML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Jackson JSON library will not detect this as different object levels. You can use this instead:

```
{
  "foo": {
       "bar": {
            "baz":"qux"
        }
  }
}
```

And you will have to create:

- Class WrapperClass containing "foo" of type FooClass
- Class FooClass containing "bar" of type BarClass
- Class BarClass containing "baz" of type String

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that by using `@JsonUnwrapped`:

```
public class Wrapper {
  @JsonUnwrapped(prefix="foo.bar.")
  public AnotherClass foo; // name not used for property in JSON
}

public class AnotherClass {
   String baz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
Iterator<String> iterator = root.fieldNames();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String fieldName = iterator.next();
    if (fieldName.contains(".")) {
        String[] items = fieldName.split("\\.");
        if (items[0].equals("foo")) {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            if (items[1].equals("bar")) {
                AnotherClass bar = new AnotherClass();
                foo.bar = bar;
                if (items[2].equals("baz")) {
                    bar.baz = root.get(fieldName).asText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```